# SDK for More Games

Tags: ios, sdk, ads

I've seen some games which have a `More Games` button, on clicking of which it redirects to a list of games where the user can download the games. I wanted to have the same functionality for my game too. Which framework, SDK or extension offers such kind of functionality. Of course I want to generate revenue per download.

The SDK I tried are `Tapjoy` and `Revmob`, but they do not give the exact solution I wanted. Tapjoy shows a single app at a time, and revmob just shows an alert, asking the user to download a random free app.

Note: I've deleted the previous question and created a new question, as the previous question was downvoted for no reason and I couldn't got any answer on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RevMob](http://www.revmob.com) offers the functionality you describe, but only for a single game that they choose, and gives you the choice of a Banner Ad, Full Screen Ad, Popup Alert (as you mention) or a link that you can set to be called directly from a button press.

Create a 'More Games' button and in its action place a call to RevMob like this,

```
  [RevMobAds openAdLink];
```

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative with RevMob is an already configure UIButton:

```
RevMobAds *revmob = [RevMobAds revMobAds];
UIButton *button = [revmob button];
```

[API documentation](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Classes/RevMobAds.html)